# How to skip a sub module in a sonar analysis in a multi module java project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have a multi module Maven project. I need to exclude one of the sub module  from sonar anlaysis.

I run the mvn sonar:sonar from parent directory.

Is there a way to specify the exclusions in pom  file or do we need to configure it in sonar qube.

Comment: I see sonar.skipmodule options are depricated in latest version.

Answer (score 22):

From the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis):

> You can either:
>
> - define property `<sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip>` in the `pom.xml` of the module you want to exclude
> - use build profiles to exclude some module (like for integration tests)
> - use Advanced Reactor Options (such as "-pl"). For example } `mvn sonar:sonar -pl !module2`

Comment: Only linking some documentation is not that helpful. Especially as in this case the page does not exist anymore. I would suggest to paste the important part and add the link for additional info.

Comment: I updated the answer with the up-to-date link and also quoted the relevant part from the documentation.

Comment: Link to documentation is broken