# How to skip sonarqube analysis of gradle module

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I have a multi module gradle java project analyzed with sonarqube.

I need to skip sonarqube analysis of one module entirely.

I was not able to find a solution in sonarqube documentation. Closest page is Narrowing The Focus, but it is about skipping files and directories while I'd like to skip entire module. 
See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Comment: I can see a maven solution, but I have gradle
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178581/how-to-skip-a-sub-module-in-a-sonar-analysis-in-a-multi-module-java-project

Comment: how did you setup your build.gradle to make sonarqube scan all modules? i've been trying but can't get it to scan more than one module at a time. thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set skipProject to true in a project you want to skip:

```
sonarqube {
    skipProject = true
}
```

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-Skippinganalysisofaproject

Comment: When i do that I have the issue that it lost my server configuration and returns to default http://localhost:9000

Comment: Looks like a bug in the 2.6.x plugin. When I bumped the version to 2.7 it honoured skipProject and didn't fail over to localhost.

Comment: `Cannot access 'skipProject': it is private in 'SonarQubeExtension'`

Comment: isSkipProject = true